Publishing message to GCP PubSub from a FastAPI app
I'm receiving a webhook from Twilio through a FastAPI application running on GCP's Cloud Run. This application receives the message and posts it to a PubSub topic. This topic has message ordering based on the phone number.
At some point, the application simply stops responding to webhooks and starts returning a 504 error. I couldn't identify where the problem is. I suspect it might be some concurrency issue when I instantiate the PubSub client. The only way to "restore" the service is by restarting the Cloud Run container.
There's nothing showing up in the error log. I'm considering enabling the logging for the PubSub Client, but I also don't know how to do that.
As I can see from the log, the last message is "Instantiating PubSub client...", then the POD stucks.

from google.cloud import pubsub
def get_pub_sub():
    return PubSub("primary-care-378721")


class PubSub:

    def __init__(self, project_name, enable_message_ordering=True) -> None:
        print("Instantiating PubSub client...")
        publisher_options = pubsub.types.PublisherOptions(
            enable_message_ordering=enable_message_ordering
        )
        self.project_name = project_name
        self.publisher = pubsub.PublisherClient(publisher_options=publisher_options)
        print("Done")

    def publish_message(
        self, topic_name: str, message: dict, ordering_key: str
    ) -> None:
        topic_path = self.publisher.topic_path(self.project_name, topic_name)
        data = json.dumps(message).encode("utf-8")
        future = self.publisher.publish(
            topic=topic_path, data=data, ordering_key=ordering_key
        )
        return future.result()

This is the Fast API Router Code:
@router.post("/incoming-message", status_code=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
async def receive_incoming_message(
    request: Request, pub_sub_client=Depends(get_pub_sub)
):
    print("Processing request...")
    form_data = await request.form()
    form_dict = form_data._dict
    ordering_key = form_dict.get("From")

    topic_name = "twilio_incoming_message-de6f415"

 
    rs = pub_sub_client.publish_message(
        topic_name=topic_name, message=form_dict, ordering_key=ordering_key
    )
    print(
        f"Message {rs} published successfully to topic {topic_name} with ordering key {ordering_key}"
    )


It seems that there is a reported bug. But still don´t know how to create a Workaroud: https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/issues/1101

I think the solution being suggested in the associated pull is that you share a pubsub_v1.PublisherClient across your threads. I'm not a FastAPI developer but, you could create the PublisherClient as a global and then use your router's state to persist it (router.state.foo = publisher) and then in your receive_incoming_request handler use the persisted publisher (i.e. router.state.foo) to publish the message.

You could drop your PubSub class since this is mostly recreating the publisher each invocation of the handler (which you don't want)

Yep! That seems to be the problem, fast api multithreads. I have used lifespan on FastApi. I suppose that it had been fixed.

I am facing the same issue, but for I do not have python-pubsub as a dependency nor subdependency.
In my case it is a LLM streaming scenario with FastAPI and after round about a week this issue appears and only restarting the cloud run instance "fixes" it.
Anyone a suggestion on how to narrow it down? I am using a ThreadPoolExecutor for retrieval. Might this be the somehow causing the issue?
@p.magalhaes did you solve it already?

@mc_plectrum Answer below.

I have solved it using the lifespan of FastAPI. (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/)
I have just initialized the Pubsub client in LifeSpan, and use it inside the routes.
@contextlib.asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    db_manager.init()
    app.state.pub_sub_client_ordered = get_pub_sub(enable_message_ordering=True)
    app.state.pub_sub_client = get_pub_sub(enable_message_ordering=False)

    yield
    await db_manager.close()


You could instead add the objects to request.state inside the lifespan handler, as explained in this answer
